# amazon s3 file download returns 404

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, download

I'm trying to download a file in s3. I followed the s3 library on https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3 but couldn't download the file. And error message is not clear. It says "Error: http status code 404". What am I missing?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var s3 = require('s3');
var stdio = require('stdio');

var client = s3.createClient({
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: "access key id",
    secretAccessKey: "secret access key",
  },
});



var params = {
    localFile: "home/download",

    s3Params: {
      Bucket:  "bucketname",
      Key: "/folder1/folder2/folder3/fileName",
    },
};

var downloader = client.downloadFile(params);
downloader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("unable to download:", err.stack);
  //err.stack returns as "Error: http status code 404"
});
downloader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log("progress", downloader.progressAmount, downloader.progressTotal);
});
downloader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done downloading");
});
```

Comment: 404 means file not found. Are you sure the file is there? What happens if you manually surf to it?

Comment: Have you permissioned access to the bucket, using IAM or Bucket Policy?

Comment: Actually, I can reach the file from DragonDisk with my secret access key and id.

Comment: `Key` should not have a leading slash.  The root of a bucket is the empty string, not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I debug your code and put a private file on S3 and got the same error while using the above code you mentioned. The problem with s3 client initialization this is how I fixed the s3 client.

If you read the documentation they mention how to configure with AWS-S3
https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3#create-a-client-from-existing-awss3-object

```
var fs = require('fs');
var s3 = require('s3');
var stdio = require('stdio');
var AWS =require('aws-sdk')

var client1 = s3.createClient({
  maxAsyncS3: 20,     // this is the default
  s3RetryCount: 3,    // this is the default
  s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default
  multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, // this is the default (20 MB)
  multipartUploadSize: 15728640, // this is the default (15 MB)
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: "***********",
    secretAccessKey: "********"
  },
});




// initilize wtih s3 client
var awsS3Client = new AWS.S3(client1);
var options = {
  s3Client: awsS3Client,
  // more options available. See API docs below.
};
var client = s3.createClient(options);

var params = {
  // local directory with file name
    localFile: "./test.jpg",

    s3Params: {
      // bucket name 
      Bucket:  "cf-logs.test.com",
      // folder and file name to download
      Key: "test/Horse Racing.jpg",
    },
};

var downloader = client.downloadFile(params);
downloader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error("unable to download:", err.stack);
  //err.stack returns as "Error: http status code 404"
});
downloader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log("progress", downloader.progressAmount, downloader.progressTotal);
});
downloader.on('end', function() {
  console.log("done downloading");
});
```

[image]